# What is an electric charge?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

If electric charge is a property of matter that puts a force on other materials. Then why each object doesn't get repelled Or attracted?

Comment: Because there are both negative and positive electric charges in nature, so the effect easily neutralizes when we talk about big objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because each object is itself *electrically neutral*: equal numbers of positive and negative charges. You can alter this in the case of electrical nonconductors by sticking a few extra electrons on the surface (giving it a net negative charge) or pulling off a few electrons (giving it a net positive charge). This is called *static electricity* and is what makes balloons stick to the walls of a room.

Comment: Thank you. This answered my question